# DFS and BFS on Adjacency Matrix, Java

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception, breadth-first-search, adjacency-matrix, microsoft-distributed-file-system

I am trying to write a program in Java which performs DFS and BFS on an adjacency matrix. The code I have so far compiles and gives the desired output so far.

However I am getting an error which I am unable to resolve which I feel may have something to do with my for loops.

The error is as follows:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 9
        at GraphMatrix.dfVisit(GraphMatrix.java:304)
        at GraphMatrix.dfVisit(GraphMatrix.java:306)
        at GraphMatrix.dfVisit(GraphMatrix.java:306)
        at GraphMatrix.DF(GraphMatrix.java:261)
        at GraphMatrix.main(GraphMatrix.java:347)
```

The code where the errors are the below snippets:

```
    // method to initialise Depth First Traversal of Graph
public void DF( int s)
{
    id = 0;

    for(int v = 1; v <= V; v++) {
        visited[v] = 0;

    }
    dfVisit(0, s); //error being signaled here

}
```

And the second on the lines from the if statment:

```
private void dfVisit( int prev, int v)
{
    visited[v] = ++id;
    System.out.println("Visited vertex" + ": " + v + "  Along edge  : " + prev);

    for (int u: adj[v]) {
       if (visited[u] != visited[v]) {

           dfVisit(prev, u);
       }
    }
}
```

And finally in the main, the g.DF(s) :

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    int s = 4;
    String fname = "wGraph3.txt";

    GraphMatrix g = new GraphMatrix(fname);

    g.display();

    g.DF(s);


    g.BF(s);

}
```

}

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

According to the stack trace, the exception is thrown from the `dfVisit()` method, apparently when evaluating the expression `visited[u] != visited[v]`.  From context, it must arise from `u` being out of bounds for array `visited` (else an exception would have been thrown earlier).  The exception message gives you the value of the out-of-bounds index (9).

Since each value `u` takes is an element of `adj[v]`, it seems reasonable to conclude that `adj[v]` contains bad data, or else that you are interpreting its contents incorrectly.  I can only speculate about how or why that may be, but my first guess would be that the elements of `adj[v]` are expressed in terms of 1-based indexing (that is, as if the smallest valid array index were 1), whereas Java uses 0-based indexing.

Comment: So basing my dfVisit method off this pseudo code, what would you suggest..

`Graph :: dfVisit( Vertex prev, Vertex v)
Begin
visited[v] = ++id
print “Visited vertex “, v, “ along edge “, prev, “—“, v
for each vertex u  adj(v)
if not visited[u]
dfVisit(u)
End`

Comment: I really can't say anything further, @AmyKelly.  I don't see anything inherently wrong with the *algorithm* you're trying to implement.  Rather, it appears that the problem is in your interpretation of the data you're working with and / or with your implementation details.  You've not presented the information needed for anyone to be more specific than I already have been.